# Search Map & Print Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have an STL map that maps a key to a vector of deliverables.
I would like to search the map for a certain key and print out all of the deliverables. I am trying to iterate through the vector and call print on each item.

```
typedef std::vector<Deliverables>      MyDeliverables;
typedef std::map<int, MyDeliverables> MyMap;

MyMap map1;

template < class T >

void printVector( const vector <T> &v)
{
    for (auto p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); ++p)
        *p->print();
}


int main()
{   
Deliverables del("Name", 12, 12, 2018);

map1.insert(MyMap::value_type(1, MyDeliverables()));

auto search = map1.find(1);
if (search != map1.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found Student ID: " << search->first << '\n';
    printVector(search->second);
}
else {
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
}
```

> Error  C2662   'void Deliverables::print(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Deliverables' to 'Deliverables &'
>     Line: *p->print();

How can I correctly print the deliverables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the code you are not showing:

```
Deliverables::print()
```

It is not `const`, so you cannot use it. Declare the print function as const, and then you can use a `const Deliverables&`:

```
Deliverables::print() const
```

Then change your loop to avoid confusion as to what to dereference and how many times:

```
for(const auto& p: v)
    p.print();
```

Comment: If the normal for is used, p->print() without extra dereference would also be necessary, at least if print() doesn't return a pointer.

Comment: @Christophe indeed, extra `*` that would be flagged by the compiler as trying to dereference a void return. Added a comment as to why changing the for loop is better.